# Java, Hibernate - How to create generic getByColumnValue() methods?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, types

I want to write a generic method that searches for a column value and returns the existing object or a new object of `type T`. `T` has a data field `String name` with the corresponding `getName()`.

this doesnt work for objects which have a name column:

```
static public <T> T getByName(Class<T> type, final String name) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<T> list = session.createCriteria(type).list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    for (T entry : list) {
        if (entry.getName().equals(name)) {
            return entry;
        }
    }
    return new Class<T>(name);//or return null and create object in the calling method
}
```

`entry` has to be cast to the concrete class of `T`, how can i achieve this? 
Is there a better approach?

**edit**

Solution based on Aaron Digulla answer:

```
static public <T> T getByName(Class<T> type, final String name) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query sqlQuery = session.createQuery("from " + type.getName() + " where name = :name");
    sqlQuery.setParameter("name", name);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<T> entries = sqlQuery.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    if (entries.size() == 1) {
        return entries.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html) for this:

```
Query q = s.createQuery("from " + type.getName() + " where name = :name");
q.setParameter("name", name);
List<T> result = q.list();
```

You can even write a method that can query arbitrary columns by passing the column name into the method as well.

Comment: thanks, but i think it should be `q.setParameter("name", name)`.